# requestAction does not work in CakePHP 2.4.1

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.4

In previous [cakephp-1.2](/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.2) and [cakephp-1.3](/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.3) I used the following code and it works fine:

```
$b = $this->requestAction(
        array('controller' => 'blocks', 'action' => 'view'),
        array('sParams' => $this->params, 'position' => $position, 'return')
    );
```

Now I use cakePHP 2.4.1 and this cuases the following error:

```
> Warning (2): rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
> given [CORE\Cake\Routing\Router.php, line 1001]
```

Followed by missing Controller error:

```
> Missing Controller
> 
> Error: Controller could not be found.
> 
> Error: Create the class Controller below in file:
> app\Controller\Controller.php
> 
> <?php class Controller extends AppController {
> 
> }
```

Is there anything I don't know changed from cakePHP 1.3 to CakePHP 2.4.1 that prevents this requestAction from working as usual?

**Edit**: In the [requestAction api documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Object.html#_requestAction), there is the following notice:

> Under the hood this method uses Router::reverse() to convert the $url
>   parameter into a string URL. ***You should use URL formats that are
>   compatible with Router::reverse()***

However, in [Router::reverse](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Router.html#_reverse) method documentation, I could not able to find any hint about its URL compatible formats.

By the way, using the default layout theme, ends this issue, which they don't use the requestAction(), but I need to use the themed view and its layout.

Comment: "Is there anything I don't know" - A lot. Start by reading the migration guides, just google "cakephp migration guide".

Comment: Already, I readed it. However, sometime, you may not able to notice something regarding your issue.

Comment: They changed *a lot*. At the very basic they don't recommend you from using `requestAction` as it's heavy. Perhaps it can be restructured into a shared component or a shared Lib?

Comment: @LionelChan The documentation said that using cache with `requestAction` improves its performance.

Comment: In fact it reads `If used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance. It is rarely appropriate to use in a controller or model.` which is true as in our full-fledged web app we doesn't even make a single `requestAction` call at all. I'm sure you can overcome yours by not using it as well ;) consider fat model?

Comment: @LionelChan Well, Is there any other way to include view action of my blocks controller to be rendered in all the website's pages else requestAction call from the layout?

Comment: Same issue here. And no, the documentation for migration is poor and does not help at all.